# How to toggle or unpress Button onclick using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I have a table (3x2) of six onclick Buttons. When I press a Button, a window with some text appear below the pressed Button. The window (or div) is remain shown until I press the same button again. Even, if I press another button, then another window is shown under that button.

My question: is there a way to make it work as "toggle" between buttons. That means, if I press a button, a window (div) appears, and if I press another button, the earlier window (div) disappears and a new one appears?

```
<button onclick="myFunction(1)">Button1</button>
<div id="myDIV1" style="display:none">
"the window with text to be shown"
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction(2)">Button2</button>
<div id="myDIV2" style="display:none">
"the window with text to be shown"
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(num) {
    var str1= "myDIV"
    var str2 = num.toString();
    var result = str1 + str2
    var x = document.getElementById(result);
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to deal with large amount of elements to toggle, the possible and efficient solution is to store the previously toggled html element ref, and hide it if user click on another button.

```js
var previouslyToggled

function myFunction(num) {
  var result = "myDIV" + num.toString();
  var x = document.getElementById(result);
  
  if (previouslyToggled && previouslyToggled !== x) {
    previouslyToggled.style.display = 'none'; 
  }
  
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
  
  // Store element ref
  previouslyToggled = x
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction(1)">Button1</button>
  <div id="myDIV1" style="display:none">
  "the window with text to be shown for btn 1"
  </div>
  <button onclick="myFunction(2)">Button2</button>
  <div id="myDIV2" style="display:none">
  "the window with text to be shown for btn 2"
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. If I press the old button, the underline text should disappear. If I press a new button, the old text should disappear and a new one appear. But I cannot achieve that. Any further help!

Comment: @moh19814 Yeah, missed that. Check my answer update.

Comment: @moh19814 Glad to help. Also do not forget to mark answer as correct if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think in plain Javascript you need to set all the other buttons display-types to none again when you another button to make it work out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of the HTML, you can target the next div element of the clicked button with `nextElementSibling`:

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  document.querySelectorAll('button + div').forEach(function(d){
    d.style.display = 'none'; // hide all
  });
  btn.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block'; // show div only next to the button clicked
}
```

```css
button{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
button+div{
  display:none; 
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">Button1</button>
<div id="myDIV1">
"the window with text to be shown"
</div>
<div id="">
.....1111
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">Button2</button>
<div id="myDIV2">
"the window 2 with text to be shown"
</div>
<div id="">
.....2222
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried to do that, but so far I press any button, everything disappear. The problem is that i have many other things (and div) on my page. I only want certain div to disappear.

Comment: @moh19814, it is really difficult to answer without seeing all the html. Though the selector `button + div` should work.....try the updated code:)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all div before show the div under the button. Example:

```
getElementsByTagName("div").style.display = "none";
x.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried to do that, but so far I press any button, everything disappear. The problem is that i have many other things (and div) on my page. I only want certain div to disappear.